# PHP 744 | Create or write permission by script security issue?

Tags: linux, security, php, php5

Given security permission of 744 in linux for PHP.

To enable create and write files by PHP script.
Also given create/write permission to folder where files going to be create/write.

Does this permission enable hacker to upload or write wrong things on server ?

Comment: A hacker, by definition, is a person who hacks your system and bypasses file permission restrictions via security holes in software. In this regard, your question has little to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended secure permissions for files is **644**, for folders **755**.
So your **744** permissions looks good and a little over-secured.

You can change permissions for whole project with this commands

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

644 means that files are readable and writable by the owner of the file and readable by users in the group owner of that file and readable by everyone else.

755 is the same thing, it just has the execute bit set for everyone. The execute bit is needed to be able to change into the directory. This is why directories are commonly set to 755.

If you have some login information in php file, like for db, I would recommend set it to 600 to prevent reading by other users expect owner.

Setting all php files to 600 makes no sense, because there is nothing secret, especially for CMS like Wordpress. But it can cause more troubles in support.

Comment: You should consider explaining why these permissions are recommended to better help future visitors understand and to give the OP some confidence in your answer.

Comment: nerdwaller, done.

Comment: Thank for answer, My trouble is allow to write/create new files in directory by php script, with exact permission & where hacker should not damage server.

Like in wordpress, without 744 it did not allow to upload files.

In my PHP code, files is created/write by php script with file IO functions.

Comment: Try 755, if it's not work for upload folder than you need set 777 permissions on upload folders. In this case protection should has been implemented by Worpress CMS while uploading in this concrete folders. You can depend on this protection. Also try to install secure plugins for Worpress like Wordfence and iThemes Security.